# Android ACRA - Application Crash Reporting for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, crash-reports, acra

I am trying to figure out how to add ACRA in my test project in Android Studio.

Following this article (which explains how to do it in Eclipse) https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup, I have passed all so far up to the point where is explains to annotate your Application class with @ReportsCrashes.  In this part, I dont know what to put as formUri.

I am just creating my own test app (API22 Lollipop) and trying to add ACRA support to it.  I don't have any server, it is just a simple Android app.

```
    import org.acra.*;
    import org.acra.annotation.*;

    @ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
        formUri = "http://www.backendofyourchoice.com/reportpath"
    )
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
    }
```

What do I put as the formUri?
Can you explain what formUri is for and how it works as I am new to dev?

Please explain

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formUri` points to your crash report server.
There are many to choose from, commercial and free.
The ACRA wiki lists several.
ACRAlyzer is one, but you will need to host it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Acralyzer: https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/setup
It is simple backend for ACRA reports.

```
@ReportsCrashes(    
        formUri = "https://[your.couchdb.host]/acra-[yourappname]/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
        formUriBasicAuthLogin="[reporteruser]",
        formUriBasicAuthPassword="[reporterpassword]",
        reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
....
        )
  public class [YourApplication] extends Application {

  @Override
  public final void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ACRA.init(this);
  }
```

There you will find the usage of the Acralyzer user interface: https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/usermanual